# Obtener el valor mas cercano pero no superior de una lista en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en la cual guardo el precio de un producto con su respectiva fecha de modificacion.

Para obtener el precio actual no tengo problema ya que consulto el ultimo valor.

Sin embargo no he podido resolver el como generar una consulta que pueda devolverme el precio en el que ese producto estaba, dada una fecha especifica.

| id_historico_precios | id_producto | precio | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 655 | 40 | 5.00 | 2023-03-01 12:02:12 |
| 656 | 40 | 15.00 | 2023-03-05 12:02:12 |
| 657 | 40 | 20.00 | 2023-03-10 12:02:12 |

Si quisiera saber a la fecha **2023-03-07 12:00:00** que precio le correspondía en ese momento, el cual deberia de regresarme el **id_historico_precio: 656**.

La duda es cual consulta pudiera servirme de mejor manera.
Muchas por su ayuda.

Comment: `fecha` es fecha de modificación?

Comment: Hola pabloarzaluz, bienvenido, Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Si asi es, se registra la fecha en que ese precio se actualizo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piensalo de la siguiente manera:

- Si filtras los resultados menores que: `fecha<='2023-03-07 12:00:00'` tendrás una lista de fechas, de las cuales la mayor de todas ellas es la que buscas.
- Entonces ordenas descendentemente, quedando la mayor arriba y te quedas con la primera.

```
select * from tabla 
where fecha<='2023-03-07 12:00:00'
order by fecha desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Gracias, me quede atascado pensando en como resolverlo.

Comment: @pabloarzaluz Todos tenemos colapsos mentales, me alegra haber podido ayudarte. Saludos